# Is there a mySQL server + JSP server package similar to a WAMP?

Tags: mysql, jsp, vps

Is there a server package that has both JSP and MySQL support?

I like how WAMP is packaged so that PHP and MySQL is in one package, is there one that has JSP instead of PHP? If not what VPS hosts would you recommend for JSP and MySQL development?

Comment: It isn't too hard to set up a Tomcat instance to talk to MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html - has servers for PHP,MySQL, Perl, and though not advertised on the main page a tomcat server as well to run JSP